# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test gives result different from max(abs(difference(x, y)))

Tags: r, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm  using `ks.test` function in r to perform Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I found that Kolmogorov-Smirnov test gives result different from

```
max(abs(difference(x, y)))
```

According to the definition of Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), the results should be equivalent.

Does any one know why?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. If you want to hunt this down yourself, sift through the code in `ks.test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KS statistic is not supposed to be equal to `max(|x-y|)`.
It is applied to the cumulative distribution function(s) (CDF). Thus, it represents rather the proportion of observations different between a sample and a reference distribution.

See the two examples below executed in [MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) (although I expect the results to be identical in [R](https://www.r-project.org/)):

```
    x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
    y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11];

    [~, ~, ks2s] = kstest2(x,y)

    ks2s =

        0.1000                       (1)



    x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
    y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12];

    [~, ~, ks2s] = kstest2(x,y)

    ks2s =

        0.1000                        (2)
```

Thus, although the maximum absolute magnitude difference between `x` and `y` is larger in (2), the KS statistic is the same because the proportion of samples that are different is the same.

If `y` has an extra sample, for example, the result changes:

```
    x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
    y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11];

    [h, p, ks2s] = kstest2(x,y)

    ks2s =

        0.0909
```